# Unable to retrieve view controller with NSProgressIndicator programatically

Tags: ios, swift, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to retrieve the actual view controller and call a method to change the ProgressIndicator.

I have the following function in my AppDelegate

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let main = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = main.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Installing") as! ViewController
    vc.incrementBar(number: 20)
}
```

The incrementBar function is as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: NSProgressIndicator!
public func incrementBar(number: Double){
    if(self.progressView != nil){
        print(number)
        self.progressView.increment(by: number)
    }
}
```

Just to be sure. I can easily call this function from viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() but as soon as i try to receive the actual controller it tells me that progressView is nil

Comment: Is the progressbar not being set to 20? Or is it not showing up at all? ... what is the result of this code?

Comment: The progressbar is there. And i can set it to twenty but only if i call it with viewDidLoad(). Hower i cannot call incrementBar from any other class.

Comment: Does calling incrementBar() cause the app to crash or does it do nothing? Also try changing the outlet from weak to strong

Comment: it would crash if i would not check for nil

Comment: did you try making the outlet strong? Apple recommends defaulting outlets to strong, unless there is a good reason for you to make it weak

Comment: i changed it but i makes no difference. The Problem is that it seems to be receiving an empty ViewController as it breaks as soon is a try to access a function or variable...

Comment: Double check to make sure you have set the ViewController Identifier correctly in the storyboard and the code.

Comment: i have. I think instantiateController is not working correctly. If i put in the wrong name i get a message imidiately....